# Trying to generate rows in a table

Tags: django, django-templates

here's what my models look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSJUv.png

I'm trying to fill out a table full of disks, each has a serial and model number.  I'm going to assume I'll do something like {% for disks in "something" %}, but I'm not quite sure what that something would be.

Here's what i was hoping for:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>Model Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

{% for disks in "something" %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ disk.serial }}</td>  
    <td>{{ disk.model }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does your view look like that renders this template?

Comment: It was just blank, was missing the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template is only part of your issue. It's actually the less complicated aspect, as all you are doing is passing it a context (a dictionary) for it to access. The step before the template is the view that is organizing the data. Lets start with that...

**View**

The function (view) that gathers the data needs to build a context containing your "disk" objects, assumably a result of a database model query. For simplicity, lets just say you did this:

```
disks = Disk.objects.all()
```

With your disks queryset, you can now deliver that to your template in the context.

```
context = {"disks": disks}
return render_to_response('my_template.html', context)
```

The context will now be passed to your template.

**Template**

Simply refer to the objects in your context:

```
{% for disk in disks %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ disk.serial }}</td>  
    <td>{{ disk.model }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

@jdi is right, but since this is something very commonly done in web development - there is a [generic view for it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#generic-views-of-objects).

In your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView
from myapp.models import Disk

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^disk_list/$', ListView.as_view(
        model=Disk,
        template_name='disk_list.html'
    )),
)
```

Create a file called `disk_list.html`, that is any directory listed in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, and in it add this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>Model Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

{% for disk in object_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ disk.serial }}</td>  
    <td>{{ disk.model }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, navigate to `http://localhost:8000/disk_list/`